# Conditional on Aspect pointcut execution

Tags: java, spring, conditional-statements, aspect, pointcut

I've been thinking of situation like pointcut'ing the pointcut. Let's say I have a situation as follows:

```java
@Around("@annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled)")
public void aroundSchedule(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    boolean success = false;

    try {
        joinPoint.proceed();

        success = true;
    } finally {
        // handle success/failure flag
    }
}
```

Now some `Schedule`s have pre-condition(s) before actual work is being done. They are dynamic and cannot be achieved in other way than calling some extra services to check. My goal is to rip that away and leave `Schedule` to do it's own unit of work. Am I too imperative or just eager to do so or what?

Now to the real question. Is there a way to depend `Pointcut` on another `Pointcut` outcome or some similar conditional approach before execution of ^ sampled one?

Answer (score 0):

In AspectJ there is an `if()` pointcut type which is unavailable in Spring AOP. So either you [switch to AspectJ](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) or you just call a utility class or method within your aspect doing the precondition checking manually.

I do not know if it is worth switching to AspectJ for the `if()` pointcut, but FYI [it works like this](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3697).

Comment: left `if()` out thinking it's still gonna be main `Pointcut` related even though it's saying to my face "conditional" :). i guess i just need to try it for once

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you are trying to say. It is the way you use English, sorry. I tried to make sense of it but failed. Maybe you can explain in other words?